# Elasticsearch couldn't start in windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

warning: ignoring JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.15; using bundled JDK
Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x64"
Using ES_JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  "C:\Program Files\elasticsearch-8.2.0\jdk"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
output:
[0.150s][error][logging] Error opening log file 'logs/gc.log': Permission denied
[0.150s][error][logging] Initialization of output 'file=logs/gc.log' using options 'filecount=32,filesize=64m' failed.
error:
Could not rename log file 'logs/gc.log' to 'logs/gc.log.10' (Permission denied).
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:114)
at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:79)
at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.MachineDependentHeap.determineHeapSettings(MachineDependentHeap.java:61)
at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:135)
at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:87)

Comment: Seems like stactrace without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing jvm.options and set Xms and Xms memory arguments?
Both should be the same value, and value should be below the total available system memory.

Also try changing log level in log4j.properties file to get some detailed error log, if that helps.